# Does Binding a control to a object count as subscribing?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, data-binding

So I am currently working with databinding in MVVM.
So my class derrives from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I am binding my control to the property in my class.
Usually when creating an event you would subscribe to it explicitly with a method like so `+= myMethod` however when doing it like this I see no `+=` but yet it works.

My question is.. 
How does my control subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event
Does my control implicitly subscribe to the event whenever I bind it to the property?

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

MasterViewModel

```
class MasterViewModel
    {
        public Username Username { get; } = new Username();
    }
```

XAML

```
<TextBox Name="tbUsername" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="381,132,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Username.TheUsername}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Class

```
class Username : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Username()
        {
            TheUsername = "Hello World!";
        }

        private string _username;

        public string TheUsername
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TheUsername");
            }
        }



        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework (WPF) takes care of the subscribing for you. It applies the weak event pattern as mentioned on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns

In short the framework checks whether the source object of a binding implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and if it does, it subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event behind the scenes. Exactly how this is handled internally in WPF is an implementation detail that you don't really have to care about or should depend upon.

Comment: So when you say `source object` you are refering to the class in which you have bound to if it implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` corrent?

Comment: Yes, the source object would be your Username instance in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you bind the += will be done for you.